# Get a pseudorandom float number in a closed interval [a, b]

Tags: ruby, random, floating-point

I would like to know the best way to get a pseudorandom float number in a closed interval using the Ruby *rand* kernel function (please not Random module).

To take an example I will use the closed interval **[0.0, 7.7]** (both 0.0 and 7.7 included in the interval), but any other float interval should be valid too.

For the interval [0.0, 7.7] the next solution **is not valid**:

```
rand * 7.7
```

Why?

If you call *rand* without arguments you will get a pseudorandom floating point number greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0. So what is the range of float numbers that the previous solutions can give to us?

*rand* will return a pseudorandom float number in the range [0.0, 0.9999999...]

```
0.0 * 7.7
=> 0.0          # Correct!

0.9999999 * 7.7
=> 7.69999923   # Incorrect!
```

The interval does not match with [0.0, 7.7].

Does anyone know an elegant solution to this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a `Random` class that can do what you want:

```
generator = Random.new # You need to instance it
generator.rand 0.0..7.7
```

(The documentation states the difference between 0.0..7.7 and 0.0...7.7 will be taken in account.)

In the future 1.9.3, you'll be able to pass a range to `Kernel#rand` and `Random.rand` (you can already do that in the preview version).

Comment: If this works, then its cool, but its not totally clear from the documentation that it treats 0.0..7.7 differently than 0.0...7.7 (i.e. that it will include the endpoint when requested).  Here are the docs:  http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Random.html#M000693   Is there anyway we could test the class in a reasonable amount of time to see if it sometimes returns the endpoint?

Comment: You linked to Random.rand. Random#rand say "prng.rand(5.0..9.0) #=> between 5.0 and 9.0, including 9.0". Looking at the C code, two different functions will be used (generate_real for 0...1.0, generate_real2 for 0..1.0).

Comment: Oh, you are right, the documentation is clear if you look in the right place (Public Instance Methods, of course).

Comment: Thank you Mon ouïe. I didn't know that Random#rand could work with ranges but I would like to know how to solve this problem with Kernel#rand. It's a cool feature for the new 1.9.3 version that ranges will be included in Kernel#rand.

Comment: I will check this solution as correct because is the most rubyist and I will use it to solve my problem. Thank you!.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of digits of precision you need you could use a round to even approach to snap to the boundaries of the interval to the edges.  Hope this helps.

Here is the text from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even)

> Round half to evenA tie-breaking rule that is even less biased is
>   round half to even, namely
>
> If the fraction of y is 0.5, then q is the even integer nearest to y.
>   Thus, for example, +23.5 becomes +24, +22.5 becomes +22, −22.5 becomes
>   −22, and −23.5 becomes −24.
>
> This method also treats positive and negative values symmetrically,
>   and therefore is free of overall bias if the original numbers are
>   positive or negative with equal probability. In addition, for most
>   reasonable distributions of y values, the expected (average) value of
>   the rounded numbers is essentially the same as that of the original
>   numbers, even if the latter are all positive (or all negative).
>   However, this rule will still introduce a positive bias for even
>   numbers (including zero), and a negative bias for the odd ones.
>
> This variant of the round-to-nearest method is also called unbiased
>   rounding (ambiguously, and a bit abusively), convergent rounding,
>   statistician's rounding, Dutch rounding, Gaussian rounding, or
>   bankers' rounding. This is widely used in bookkeeping.
>
> This is the default rounding mode used in IEEE 754 computing functions
>   and operators.

Comment: Jeremy can you give an example of you idea?. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
Fineness = 2**64
puts rand(Fineness+1)*7.7/Fineness
```

Whenever `rand` returns its maximum possible value, you will get `Fineness*7.7/Fineness` which turns out to equal 7.7 exactly (but I'm not totally sure this will always be the case, because floats are inexact).

As long as Fineness has more bits in it than a [double](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) on your computer, then I believe you will not notice any strangeness in the distribution of your results.

Comment: David I think that with your solution you will never get 0.0 and the solution must include closed intervals i.e. [0.0, 7.7] that include 0.0 and 7.7 in the returned values. Thanks.

Comment: I think you misread my solution.  `rand(Fineness+1)` is different from `rand(Fineness)+1`.  Whenever `rand` returns 0, my solution will give you 0.0.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

> > (rand/0.9999999999999999...)*7.7

Basically, normalize the random number by the largest possible random number.  That way you will create the range [0..1].

However, I am unsure how to get the max number, which is less than 1.0 in ruby.

Comment: I think that this could be a possible solution but as you have said you need to know the largest number that the function _rand_ can return to normalize it correctly (maybe we can use a ver large number i.e 0.999999999999999999999 but I don't know if this is correct).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need this?  I don't know of a case where there would be a need for this as a true single or double precision number.  On the other hand, there are real cases where you might need numbers between 0.0 and 7.7 in increments of 0.1.  In that case you could use well established techniques to go from 0 to 77 and then divide by 10.